# Jasny Bootstrap jquery slide should not push container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I am using [Jasny Bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/) for my sidebar but I want to make the main container not being pushed to the right side of the window but instead be squeezed in instead.

I notice that this `this.slide(elements, offset, $.proxy(complete, this))` line on the `OffCanvas.prototype.show` is causing it to be pushed to the side.

I was able to make it "squeeze" but the animation is not working anymore. I added these lines on the `OffCanvas.prototype.slide`:

```
if (placement == 'left') {
    placement = 'margin-left';
}
if (placement == 'right') {
    placement = 'margin-right';
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e02e1rwp/1/

Comment: Why do you use such an inferior framework like jasny bootstrap?

Comment: The reason why I am using jasny is just for the sidebar. Bootstrap does not have this sidebar functionality and the closest base on my needs in this. Do you know any plugin or such that has the same functionality?